# Make Xcode treat man pages like doc sets?

Tags: xcode, macos, manpage

Working with--for example--OpenGL, say I need to get documentation for `glEnable()`. Double-click, copy, Help->Open man Page..., paste, enter *works*, but...

Is there a way to make Xcode treat man pages like doc sets, so that option-double-clicking on a symbol will pull up a man page, if available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works automatically as of Xcode 4.